# How to I align vertical buttons next to image?

Tags: html, css

Please help me align my image next to the buttons. I would also like to make the buttons sit on top of each other but next to the image

```css
.body{
  background-color:#dbdbdb;
}
button{
  width:200px;
  height:60px;
  margin-right:10px;
 
}
```

```html
</div>
<div class="body">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><img id="business"src="http://fullhdpictures.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Business-People-Photos-HD.jpg"/></td>
      <td> <button id="plan" type="button">PLANNING</button></td>
      <td> <button id="strat" type="button">STRATEGY</button></td>
      <td> <button id="res" type="button">RESULTS</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: The `<table>` element is there to display *tabular data*, not an image next to a navigation menu.

Comment: Can you add a picture with the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.body{
  background-color:#dbdbdb;
}
button{
  width:200px;
  height:60px;
  margin-right:10px;
 
}
td {
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
</div>
<div class="body">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><img id="business"src="http://fullhdpictures.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Business-People-Photos-HD.jpg"/></td>
      <td> 
         <div>
            <button id="plan" type="button">PLANNING</button>
            <button id="strat" type="button">STRATEGY</button>
            <button id="res" type="button">RESULTS</button>
         </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `flexbox`, less markup, better flexibility and semantically more correct than `table`

```css
.body {
  display: flex;
}
.body > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}


/* for demo purpose I made image smaller so one can see the layout */
.body > img {
  display: block;
  width: 420px;
  height: 276px;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <img id="business" src="http://fullhdpictures.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Business-People-Photos-HD.jpg" />
  <div>
    <button id="plan" type="button">PLANNING</button>
    <button id="strat" type="button">STRATEGY</button>
    <button id="res" type="button">RESULTS</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this and the buttons aligned but the picture became stretched out.

Comment: @TGIM0791 Then you missed something while copying my code, post it and I will look ... as using `table` is really not the way to go, but it is your call

Answer (score 0):

Take it out of table and put the nav items in a div with same height as the image and set a vertical-align: middle; this will place the element in the middle of that parent div element

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your style sheet:

```
Table td
{
Verticale-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try vertical align:top

**Example :**

```css
.body{
  background-color:#dbdbdb;
}
button{
  width:200px;
  height:60px;
  margin-right:10px;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><img id="business"src="http://fullhdpictures.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Business-People-Photos-HD.jpg"/></td>
      <td style="vertical-align:top;"> <button id="plan" type="button">PLANNING</button></td>
      <td style="vertical-align:top;"> <button id="strat" type="button">STRATEGY</button></td>
      <td style="vertical-align:top;"> <button id="res" type="button">RESULTS</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#plan {
    background-color: #B21589;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    font-size: 9px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

link:-[Alignment of Buttons Next to Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180430/alignment-of-buttons-next-to-image)